# SED: Move multiple lines to the end of a text file

Tags: sed, lines

I want to move **multiple lines** using SED to the **end of a file**. For example:

```
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
STUVWX
YZ1234
```

should become:

```
STUVWX
YZ1234
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
```

Comment: Huh? They are both one line but your question is about multiple lines.

Comment: With the availability to store variables, AWK is more adapted to this usage.

Comment: @Zulu `sed` has enough storage for this task.

Comment: You could edit it instead of quickly downvoting it...

Answer (score 12):

The question asks a method for using `sed` to move multiple *lines*.  Although the question, as currently edited, does not show multiple lines,  I will assume that they are actually meant to be separate lines.

To use `sed` to move the first three lines to the end:

```
$ cat file
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
STUVWX
YZ1234
$ sed '1,3{H;d}; ${p;x;s/^\n//}' file  
STUVWX
YZ1234
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
```

Explanation:

- `1,3{H;d}`

  The `1,3` restricts these commands to operation only on lines 1 through 3.  `H` tells `sed` to save the current line to the hold buffer.  `d` tells `sed` not to print the current line at this time.
- `${p;x;s/^\n//}`

  The `$` restricts this command to the last line.  The `p` tells `sed` to print the last line.  `x` exchanges the pattern buffer and hold buffer.  The lines that we saved from the beginning of the file are now in the ready to be printed.  Before printing, though, we remove the extraneous leading newline character.
- Before continuing to the next line, `sed` will print anything left in the pattern buffer.

If you are on Mac OSX or other BSD platform, try:

```
sed -e '1,3{H;d;}' -e '${p;x;s/^\n//;}' file
```

#### Using head and tail

If you are already familiar with `head` and `tail`, this may be a simpler way of moving the first three lines to the end:

```
$ tail -n+4 file; head -n3 file
STUVWX
YZ1234
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
```

#### Alternative `sed` command

In the comments, potong suggests:

```
$ sed '1,3{1h;1!H;d};$G' file
STUVWX
YZ1234
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
```

The combination of `h`, `H`, and `G` commands eliminate the need for a substitution command to remove the extra newline.

Comment: A simpler sed solution might be: `sed '1,3{1h;1!H;d};$G' file`

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `awk`

```
awk '{print $4,$5,$1,$2,$3}' file
STUVWX YZ1234 ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR
```

PS, this is multiple fields, not lines.

To write it back to the original file

```
awk '{print $4,$5,$1,$2,$3}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

---

If data is in this format:

```
cat file
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
STUVWX
```

Then this may do:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {print a[4],a[5],a[1],a[2],a[3]}' OFS="\n" file
STUVWX
YZ1234
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `ex` should do:

```
ex file <<< $'1,3m$\nw'
```